# Uncaught ReferenceError: massactionJsObject is not defined

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am adding new logic to Affiliate module from MageStore.
I want add MassAction for enabling/disabling coupons code in accounts. But when I add method _prepareMassaction, I have error when try disable coupon:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: couponGrid_massactionJsObject is not defined is not defined
```

Comment: are you able to add what's in your `_prepareMassaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution after reading 
 [Mass action in widgets](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/mass-action-in-widgets)

I created custom class and override **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction** 
and changed method **getJavaScript**(). 
I removed `var` and it started work

Answer (score 2):

Add below in Grid block of your module where you are facing the issue.

```
 protected function getAdditionalJavascript() {
       return 'window.couponGrid_massactionJsObject = couponGrid_massactionJsObject;';
//'window.{gridId}_massactionJsObject = {gridId}_massactionJsObject;';
    }
```